# Wordpress - Image Alt doesn't work on Wordpress galleries

Tags: javascript, wordpress, alt

I tried to use the search but couldn't find any solution.
For some reason my alt values not working under my website (WordPress) galleries, for example:
http://www.ettiphotography.com/gallery/las-vegas-wedding-photographer/

On homepage or blog it does work.
Of course all the images has ALT values.

Please help me find the solution for this problem ...

Thank you!

Comment: Which image are we talking about ? I inspected the images in the strip at bottom of the page and they don't have alt attribute.

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

The Fotorama plugin you are using is not retrieving the alt values from WordPress. You may need to use a different plugin in order to get the alt tags to display in a gallery.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I can't see Fotorama plugin in my admin (under plugins), Am I missing something?

Please elaborate ...

Comment: Fotorama appears to be a jQuery library for creating galleries. Some plugin or theme you have is using it to create the gallery, and that plugin or theme isn't adding the alt tags.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I'll pass this information to the tech guy, I hope he can understand how to solve it.